# Maven + system Date

Tags: maven-2, date

I'm working in a project that already have a **build process running with maven**.

Today the build generates a zip file in a given directory, but I need to add the **DATE** pattern in the file, something like `200917_projectName.zip`

Someone have any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the build-number-maven-plugin allows you to generate a property that can then be used in the `finalName` property.

The following configuration sets a timestamp property with the format you required, then modifies the finalName to use that property and result in an artifact with that name being output to the target directory.

*Note that this name is ignored when installing/deploying the artifact, otherwise Maven would not be able to reliably locate artifacts.*

```
<build>
  <finalName>${buildNumber}_${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>create</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <format>{0,date,yyyyMM}</format>
        <items>
          <item>timestamp</item>
        </items>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  ...
  </plugins>
...
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) is what you're looking for. Check the [usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) page.